# Prove that $(1,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{65}}{4})$ is an integral basis for $K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> Prove that $\left(1,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{65}}{4}\right)$ is an integral basis for $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{13})$.
>
> What is $d(K)$?

I could not do this question. Can you help me please? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, $\;\dim K_{\Bbb Q}=4\;$ , so the ring of integers here is a free abelian group of rank four. Thus, it is enough to prove the given elements are linearly independent (either over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ or over $\;\Bbb Z\;$ ...why?) to prove your point.

Comment: @DonAntonio I am sorry if I am annoying you, but I am not convinced this is enough to prove that something is an integral basis. An integral basis is defined as a $\Bbb Z$-Basis of $O_K$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module. This is stronger than claiming that it is a $\Bbb Q$-Basis of $K$.  We had this very same discussion in another question the other day: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614908/how-to-show-that-1-alpha-alpha2-2-is-an-integral-basis-of-r-mathcalo-ca/615245#615245

Comment: First, why would you annoy me at all, @benh? If you're wrong I tell you, and if I'm wrong I thank you. In this case I'm assuming it is clear (?) the given four elements are in fact integral...

Comment: Oh, I didn't even remember that post, @benh. We seem to be working with two different versions of "integral basis", and I'm not sure where we *actually* differ. In the present case, I mean a set of elements that span the field over the rational *but* that also are integral elements...

Comment: @DonAntonio great :) Then let's see, maybe I am missing something. I agree, the four elements are integral. My point is: In the question above the $\Bbb Q$-Basis $1,\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{13}, \sqrt{65}$ is a basis for $K$ consisting of integral elements. These are four linearly independent element over both $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$. However, they don't form a $\Bbb Z$-Basis of $O_K$, as $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is in $O_K$, but not in the $\Bbb Z$-span of the considered elements.

Comment: Of course, those element must *also* span (over $\;\Bbb Z\;$) the ring of integers in that extension...

Comment: Ok, I think we both agree...and I were wrong and you were right, I think, in that old post, so thanks.

Comment: So we need three conditions here:(1) an integral basis must be formed by integral elements s.t. (2) that set spans the extension field over the rationals and also (3) it is a set of (free) generators of the ring of integers. Do you agree, @benh ?

Comment: I think we can throw away condition (2)...?

Comment: great, I agree. I was already fearing there were two different inconsistent definitions of integral basis out there. So, thank you for saving me :) As far as I know, the most difficult part in showing that something is an integral basis is to actually calculate $O_K$ in order to be sure that a given basis does indeed generate the ring of integers.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the following proposition:

Let $L,L'$ be number fields of degrees $n,n'$ over $\Bbb Q$ such that $L \cap L' = \Bbb Q$. Let $(w_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ and $(w'_j)_{j=1,\dots,n'}$ be the integral basis of $L$ and $L'$ respectively. Suppose the discriminants $d,d'$ of $L,L'$ are relatively prime. Then
$$(w_iw'_j)_{\substack{i=1,\dots,n  \\ j=1,\dots,n'}}$$ is an integral basis for $LL'\mid \Bbb Q$ and the discriminant is given by $d^{n'}d'^n$.